# How to make Image in ScrollView behave like MapView

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiscrollview

I am building an application where I want to display a floor plan where the image is 1260x1000, larger than the size of my view controller. I want the user to be able to pan the image and zoom in and out, similar to how a map behaves in Mapview. How can I adjust my ScrollView attributes to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, make sure your scroll view has a maximum zoom scale larger than the default of 1.0. You can change this in Interface Builder if you want, or use the [maximumZoomScale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619408-maximumzoomscale) property in code.
2. Make your controller delegate of your scroll view .. scrollView.delegate = self
3. Make sure your view controller conform to the [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate) protocol, then add the [viewForZooming(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619426-viewforzooming) method, like this:

   ```
     func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

       return imageView
   }
   ```

So basically your code will look similar to this one

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"))
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.3
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

        func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The image is panning the way id like but the pinch zoom isn't working. I made sure the min and max zoom scales match on the ViewController and the main.storyboard.